# localizing asp.net mvc annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, data-annotations

I can localize most of data annotations in asp.net mvc. But, for some of them I can't. For example look at this one:

```
public class TestModel {
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName="MyFloat",ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(MyResource))]
    [Display(Name = "MyFloat", ResourceType = typeof(MyResource))]
    public float MyFloat { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I can localize `Required` and `Display` attributes. But, if end-user type a string in field, the validator throws an error with this message:

> The field MyFloat must be a number.

I searched all attributes to find an attribute to change this message, but I couldn't. Have you any idea please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found some information that might help you here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395040/globally-localize-validation/5395297#5395297

Comment: There is a possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099466/the-field-must-be-a-number-how-can-change-this-message-to-another-lenguage

Comment: Try disabling scripting in browser and see if it works as expected - this could be jQuery validate that overrides your string.

Answer (score 2):

I found it easier to just add this data annotation:

```
 [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessageResourceName="MyFloat",ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(MyResource))]
```

It works client side

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the `Range` attribute:

```
[Range(float.MinValue, float.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceName = "IncorrectFloat", ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Resources))]
public float MyFloat { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of sequence of events. Framework's vs your custom ones.

The default message you receiving is built deeply into the framework. It is a string resource. Default model binder is adding it when binding string value to double type. This is obviously done **before** your custom validation is and hence you getting this default error message first.

To change this behavior you might want write a *custom model binder*.
Example of how to create custom model binder is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246608/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-model-binding).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If it's client-side you're worried about just add this either to the end of the jquery.validate.js file or on a separate javascript file and reference it right after:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
  required: "Este campo es obligatorio.",
  remote: "Por favor, llenar este campo.",
  email: "Debe escribir una dirección de correo válida",
  url: "Debe escribir una dirección válida.",
  date: "Debe escribit una fecha válida.",
  dateISO: "Debe escribit una fecha (ISO) válida.",
  number: "Debe escribir un número válido.",
  digits: "Por favor, esribir sólo dígitos.",
  creditcard: "Debe escribir un número de tarjeta válido.",
  equalTo: "Por favor, escribir el mismo valor nuevamente.",
  accept: "Por favor, escribir un valor con una extensión aceptada.",
  maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, no escribir más de {0} caracteres."),
  minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, no escribir menos de {0} caracteres."),
  rangelength: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, escribir un valor entre {0} y {1} caracteres."),
  range: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, escribir un valor entre {0} y {1}."),
  max: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, escribir un valor menor o igual a {0}."),
  min: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, escribir un valor mayor o igual a {0}.")
});
```

That should localize your messages.

Comment: Note: this is the easiest way to hard code the jquery.validate localizations. For projects with multiple possible localizations I have a folder with all the localized .js files (validate-es.js, validate-us.js, etc) and decide which one to render from the BundleConfig method and the configured locale on the web.config